# Can the Osmorc plugin for IntelliJ create a Bundle Version number with a timestamp?

Tags: intellij-idea, osgi

I am using the osmorc plugin in IntelliJ to build OSGI modules. This allows me to define a bundle version. I would like the bundle version to include a timestamp for each build, `1.0.1.201204241456` for example.

Can osmorc support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the plugin uses bnd under the covers, then you should be able to use 1.0.1.${tstamp}

You can format the printout, see http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Macros

However, I am not 100% sure it (still) uses bnd under the covers

Comment: `Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.201204250618` - PERFECT!